# Unable to access an app deployed in wildfly using IP address of the system

Tags: jakarta-ee, window, wildfly-10, web-deployment-project

I have deployed the the java webapp on the server successfully with desired changes in the standalone.xml file. 
for your information, OS platform is Windows 10 and trying to access the app from the same machine using IP address. 
Accessing URL is: http://192.168.1.11:8080

Here my doublt is, even it is deployed properly, i am not able to access it in the browser with an error "The site can't be reached". i have also created a inbound rule for port 8080 but still not working.

Please anyone let me know what i am doing wrong or missing. Thanks!

**log for Wildfly:**

```
...

22:37:38,784 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on 192.168.1.11:8080

...

22:38:48,387 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 51) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "munsiji-service.war" (runtime-name : "munsiji-service.war")

22:38:49,403 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://192.168.1.11:9990/management

22:38:49,403 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://192.168.1.11:9990

22:38:49,403 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: WildFly Full 10.1.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.2.0.Final) started in 118898ms - Started 843 of 1094 services (405 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
```

Comment: It looks like WildFly starts correctly. You could try disabling the firewall in Windows to see if it's the firewall blocking access.

Comment: Thanks @JamesR.Perkins for your response. I have disabled the firewall but still same issue. Command which i have used to disable firewall is:
#netsh advfirewall set allprofiles state off

Comment: I'm not really a Windows expert so I'm not too sure.

Answer (score 0):

in the standalone.xml file find "interface name="public"" tag and make it like below:

```
<interface name="public">
    <any-address/>
</interface>
```